# How to Change the X-axis using Graph View Demo in android

Tags: android, graph

Basically i want to draw a graph where x-axis gives you the date and y axis gives u the count

I am getting data from server and parsing it in my two array's one is for count and other is for date

i am getting values in two array like this

SoapObject o=(SoapObject)p2.getProperty(xx);
                UserCallStatusBean ld=new UserCallStatusBean();

```
            if(o.getProperty("Month").toString().equals("anyType{}")){
                ld.setDuration("");
            }
            else{
                ld.setDuration(o.getProperty("Month").toString());
            }


            ld.setCount(Integer.parseInt(o.getProperty("Count").toString()));


            CallStatus.add(ld);
            GraphViewData o1=new GraphViewData(_iLoopCounter,Double.parseDouble(o.getProperty("Count").toString()));
            String o2=new String(o.getProperty("Month").toString());
            //String o2=new String(String.valueOf(_iLoopCounter));

            arrData[xx]=o1;
            arrXaxis[xx]=o2;
            _iLoopCounter++;
```

After Getting the Value in two array i use Graph View Demo to create a grapg like

```
            setContentView(R.layout.graphs);

        // init example series data
        exampleSeries = new GraphViewSeries(arrData);

        // graph with dynamically genereated horizontal and vertical labels
        GraphView graphView;
        graphView = new BarGraphView(
                    this,"");

        graphView.addSeries(exampleSeries); // data
        graphView.setScalable(true);
        graphView.setScrollable(true);
        graphView.setViewPort(2,6);
        graphView.setScrollable(true);
        graphView.setHorizontalLabels(arrXaxis);
        graphView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        graphView.setBaselineAlignedChildIndex(4);

        //graphView.setHorizontalLabels(labels);

        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.graph1);
        layout.addView(graphView);
```

Now My issue of concern is i am getting value of count on y-axis but i am also getting count of date on x-axis instead i want to show the date on x-axis

I Have read various articles to get string value on x-axis ,finded one  to use Cutom lavel formatter , But didnt knw how to use  so what i can do to get x-axis ? (Date Value)

I hope u understands ,Expecting Answer Pleasue will b aLl Mine
Thanks in advance

Comment: hi , raghav have you got the answer or not ??/

Comment: @Bhupendra Welll i have got the answer but i am not following this approach

Comment: can you post you solution here??

Comment: I have used the Steema Chart to prepare the Chart i can give you the tutorial it is 
http://www.steema.com/tags/android